# How to access QPushButton from another python file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am creating an application and have a python file for button methods. I am trying to change the stylesheet of the button by clicking on it, however, I cannot alter the button from outside the class.

Example: (ui is from a QtDesigner UI file)

Python file Main:

```
class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(ButtonMethods.buttonPushButtonClicked)
```

Python file ButtonMethods:

```
from Main import Main
def buttonPushButtonClicked():
    Main.button.setStyleSheet(...)
```

Is it possible to do it this way? I have many buttons and I don't want to cram all the methods into the same class.

Comment: better put all in one class

Comment: if you really have to do it in two files then function should get instance of main class - `def buttonPushButtonClicked(window):  window.button.setStyleSheet(...)` and then assign it with argement - ie. `connect(lambda: ButtonMethods.buttonPushButtonClicked(self))` - where `self` is instance of `Main` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer to put all in one class and use `self` instead of `Main` in `buttonPushButtonClicked`

```
class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.buttonPushButtonClicked)  # <-- self (window instance)

    def buttonPushButtonClicked(self):  # <-- self (window instance)
        self.button.setStyleSheet(...)  # <-- self (window instance)
```

If you need it as external then you should send also send instance of `Main` as argument - but this way you will have to do it manually - ie. using `lambda` to assign function with argument`

```
import ButtonMethods

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda:ButtonMethods.buttonPushButtonClicked(self)) # <-- self (window instance)

# --- file ButtonMethods.py ---

def buttonPushButtonClicked(window):  # <-- window instance
    window.button.setStyleSheet(...)  # <-- window instance
```

---

**BTW:** this way you can send button instance `self.button` instead window instance `self`

```
import ButtonMethods

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda:ButtonMethods.buttonPushButtonClicked(self.button)) # <-- self.button (button instance)

# --- file ButtonMethods.py ---

def buttonPushButtonClicked(button):  # <-- button instance
    button.setStyleSheet(...)         # <-- button instance
```

and then you can use the same function with different buttons.

But maybe you should use class `PushButton` to create own class `MyPushButton`.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking of organizing them in an external file because I have over 30 buttons on the gui, would make the file very complex and hard to edit.